# Что делать, если модель при воспроизведении анимации вращается?

Tags: unity3d

Здравствуйте, уважаемые знатоки.

Unity 3d(v.4.0) изучаю недавно и при познании Mecanim натолкнулся на такую проблему:

У меня есть анимированная модель человека в формате FBX (сделанная в 3DMax), после импорта модели на вкладке «Rig» назначаю гуманоидный тип анимации «Animation Type > Humanoid», после чего перехожу на вкладку «Animations», при выборе анимации персонажа индикаторы «Loop match» горят зеленым цветом, что означает правильную зацикленость персонажа, но при анимации персонаж вращается.

**Вопрос:** что делать, если модель при воспроизведении анимации вращается?

**P.S. Если выбрать тип «Legacy» или «Generic» анимация воспроизводится корректно.**

Спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 1):

Надо посмотреть в настройках анимации RootTransformRotation. Там может быть задан угол поворота.  Если не поможет то попробовать этот поворот отключить насовсем